# get_posts() and filters

Tags: filters

I've added a custom filter function for `the_posts` filter in a plugin.

```
add_filter('the_posts', 'posts_filter');
function posts_filter() { … }
```

This works pretty well in the main loop, that means the posts are filtered in the way I defined in the `posts_filter` function.

But I am calling `get_posts()` within an ajax request to get some posts. And there the filters aren't working. `query_posts()` or custom `wp_query` don't work too.

So the question is: How can I get posts beside the main loop which are filtered by `the_posts` filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`the_posts` does work for all queries including the main query as well as custom queries but doesn't work when using `get_posts()`. This is because `get_posts()` automatically suppresses all the filters. If you want to use the filters even when using `get_posts`, you can pass an extra key `'suppress_filters' => false` in the array you pass as argument to `get_posts()`

Comment: Hi Mridul. I thought so too. But for me it isn´t working in this case (not with custom queries and not with get_posts).

Comment: Could the problem be that my filter is set in a plugin? When I set a second filter in the functions.php file of my theme this filter is used correctly.

Comment: plugin or theme shouldn't be a problem. Did you use `is_admin()` condition in plugin? It returns true for all ajax requests even if they come from frontend.

Comment: Yes I do. You´re right. Thanks! But I need to not filter posts in the admin area. Any idea on this?

Comment: Yup, just add another condition `if(defined('DOING_AJAX') && DOING_AJAX)`. This one is true only in ajax requests